# Speeding up the removal of pages of a deactivated website from Google cache

Tags: google-search, blogger, cache

I just deleted a old blog from Blogger that barely got any visitors. How long will pages from it keep showing up in the Google cache?

Is there a way that I can I make Google forget about it faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an URL removal request at https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals
The few times i used the tool, it took less than a week for the requests to be processed.

Comment: thanks, just submitted a request... hopefully it's approved

Comment: this worked, but be warned, it doesn't remove the page from google completely - you have to specifically say which search term you don't want the page to show up for